# Split file with pattern in UNIX script

Tags: unix

I have a file I would like to split. The file would have a header and tailer record. The body of the file contains NFD and IV records. IV records are optional. Inside the NFD record, it will contain the word English or French or Français somewhere. For English, I would like the NFD and IV go to en.txt else go to fr.txt.
Here is the example:

```
 1. 000000000000000;HDR;1;...
 2. 000000008651776;NFD;Individual;...;English;...
 3. 000000008651776;IV;....
 4. 000000008657876;NFD;Individual;...;English;...
 5. 000000008751796;NFD;Individual;...;French;...
 6. 000000008751796;IV;...
 7. 999999999999999;TRL;...
```

I would like line 1, 2, 3, 4, 7 all go to en.txt, and line 1, 5, 6, 7 go to fr.txt
Any suggestion using K-shell script?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this task you need to implement state resolution. I do not think ksh only as vital solution.

awk solution in case wanted:

```
$ awk '
/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9];HDR/ { enfile=enfile $0 RS; frfile=frfile $0 RS; }
/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9];NFD.*;English/ { enflag=1; frflag=0; enfile=enfile $0 RS; }
/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9];NFD.*;French/ { enflag=0; frflag=1; frfile=frfile $0 RS; }
/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9];IV/ { if ( enflag==1 ) enfile=enfile $0 RS; if ( frflag==1 ) frfile=frfile $0 RS; }
/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9];TRL/ { enfile=enfile $0; frfile=frfile $0; }
END { print(enfile) > "en.txt"; print(frfile) > "fr.txt"; }
' en_fr.txt

$ cat en.txt
000000000000000;HDR;1;...
000000008651776;NFD;Individual;...;English;...
000000008651776;IV;....
000000008657876;NFD;Individual;...;English;...
999999999999999;TRL;...

$ cat fr.txt
000000000000000;HDR;1;...
000000008751796;NFD;Individual;...;French;...
000000008751796;IV;...
999999999999999;TRL;...
```

Note: I am not using regexp style: `/^[0-9]{15}/` in order to have native awk compatibility if You are on UNIX.

Comment: Thank you Kubator, it works. Since I am new to UNIX scripts, would you mind to explain it?

Comment: Basically awk does actions on specified states (regexps). So I defined regular expressions in // per Your example and corresponding actions.
/regexp/ { commands }
END { commands }
For example on /header/ I save whole line ($0) plus line separator (RS by default new line) for both en and fr files. Second example /english/ I enable english flag, disable frech flag and save line to en file. ... and so on.
In the END I print both en and fr files out.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do what you want.  This was written in `ksh` on Linux but will work with `bash` or others on most versions of Unix.

```
#!/bin/ksh
rm -f english.out
rm -f french.out
output=both
while read linein
do
    echo $linein | grep HDR     >/dev/null && output=both
    echo $linein | grep English >/dev/null && output=english
    echo $linein | grep French  >/dev/null && output=french
    echo $linein | grep TRL     >/dev/null && output=both
    case $output in
    both)
        echo "$linein" >> english.out
        echo "$linein" >> french.out
    ;;
    english)
        echo "$linein" >> english.out
    ;;
    french)
        echo "$linein" >> french.out
    ;;
    esac
done < data.txt
```

By way of explanation:

1. Remove the old output files at the start.
2. Set the `output` variable to both.
3. The while loop is reading in the `data.txt` file, one line at a time
   into the `linein` variable.  (The `while...done` loop has its input redirected from the `data.txt` file.)
4. (Some people will find this untidy) We echo each line to grep, throwing away the output and only keeping the exit status.  If the exit status is success, we set the output.  If the exit status is false, we don't change the output. This allows us to send the NFD records to the same place as the preceding record.
5. The case switches between the different output values to decide where to send the output.  I expect you know that `>>` means append the output to the file.  Observe the quotes around `$linein`.  If they are not there, you won't preserve the spaces in the input.  That does not appear to matter in your case.

If you only want to look for English or French in field 5, it gets more complicated (and does not work with `bash` (or with old versions of `ksh`)):

```
#!/bin/ksh
rm -f english.out
rm -f french.out
output=unknown
while read linein
do
    if [[ $linein == {15}(\d)\;HDR* || $linein == {15}(\d)\;TRL* ]]
    then
        output=both
    else
        if [[ $linein == {15}(\d)\;+([A-Z])\;+([^\;])\;+([^\;])\;+([^\;])\;* ]]
        then
            case ${.sh.match[5]} in
                English)
                    output=english
                ;;
                French)
                    output=french
                ;;
                *)
                    echo "unknown language: ${.sh.match[5]}" >&2
                    output=both
                ;;
            esac
        fi
    fi
    case $output in
        both)
            echo "$linein" >> english.out
            echo "$linein" >> french.out
        ;;
        english)
            echo "$linein" >> english.out
        ;;
        french)
            echo "$linein" >> french.out
        ;;
        *)
        echo "Unknown output: $output" >&2
        ;;
    esac
done < data.txt
```

The `${.sh.match[5]}` contains the #5 subexpression in the match string (the pieces inside the paren `()`).

Pulling subexpressions out using `awk` is simpler but this is a pure `ksh` solution.